# Passing this pointer to a templated member variable

Tags: c++, this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class C>
class Bar
{
    public:
     Bar(C& c) : _c(c) {};
     ~Bar(){};

    private:
     C& _c;
};

class Foo
{
    public:
     Foo() : bar(this) {}; //instead of bar(*this)
     ~Foo(){};

    private:
     Bar<Foo> bar;
};


int main() {
    // your code goes here
    Foo f;
    return 0;
}
```

I want to pass `this` pointer by reference to the class `Bar` templated on `Foo`. What is the syntax to do it if I don't want to dereference `this` while constructing `bar`?

ideone link: http://ideone.com/jGviBM

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Also why not store a C* instead of a C& and accept a C* as a parameter to your constructor?

Comment: This is going to be dangerous no matter how you go about it, with a partly-constructed or partly-destroyed object visible at times...

Comment: @Maria With this particular design, I'd rather have a reference to C than a pointer because different implementations of `Bar` might template it on various different things. I want to use references in this case to avoid dealing with a NULL pointer case.

@aschepler : What do you mean? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: `this` can't be `nullptr`, so you can always safely dereference it at the callers side.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ : For my case, I don't have to worry about it. But some other instantiation and of `Bar ` might not pass a `this` pointer.

Comment: @armundle What's the problem that you're trying to solve using this design pattern? If you could post that, perhaps we could suggest a better pattern.

Comment: @armundle So if some other class `Foo2`  does not pass a `this` ptr to bar, you want just a defaultley constructed `Foo2` in the `bar`?

Comment: @Maria: I want to instantiate an object (`Bar`) owned by another object (`Foo`). `Bar` will call back into `Foo` in its methods. `Bar` is just a wrapper class used by some other library to interact with with `Foo`.

Some other class (`Foo2`) can instantiate `Bar`, but let's say it templates it on `Qux`, which happens to be also a member of `Foo2`. Now, I will pass `Qux` as reference to `Bar` in the initialization list.

Comment: @armundle _"But some other instantiation and of Bar might not pass a this pointer."_ Isn't that exactly prevented using the by reference parameter? I don't get what you're bothering about. It's perfect as you already have it.

Comment: @armundle So I'm still confused about what you mean by "different implementations of `Bar` might template it on various different things". Template what? C? Bar? Don't you control the implementation of both of those things?

Comment: *Sorry, different **instantiation** of `Bar` in other classes - `Foo2`, etc.

Comment: @armundle Are you saying that the template parameter for `Bar` in the class `Foo2` is something other than `Foo2`?

Comment: @armundle Also I think you're going to have some sort of circular deletion here. E.g call delete on Foo which deletes Bar which then tries to delete the same Foo. This is really dangerous. You have to have your C& be a C* if you're going to use bar in this way.

Comment: @Maria: Yep. Decided on making it a pointer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to make a constructor that takes in a `C *`, but either way you will have to dereference the pointer:

```
template<class C>
class Bar
{
    public:
     Bar(C& c) : _c(c) {};
     Bar(C* c) : _c(*c) {};
     ~Bar(){};

    private:
     C& _c;
};
```

You can also make a separate `Bar` class/change your current class to hold a pointer instead of a reference, too, as [πάντα ῥεῖ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1413395/%CF%80%CE%AC%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%B1-%E1%BF%A5%CE%B5%E1%BF%96) pointed out.